# Tizen - how to change button font-size - fixed

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile, font-size, tizen

how can I change a button font-size? when I tried to change it with css, this changes didn't work and also buttons lost data-style: round attribute. I have an html app and button just open another page, here is it:

```
<p><a href="two.html" data-role="button"
                 data-style="round" id="btn" style="border: 5;
                  background: #FFFFFF">
                test</a></p>
```

css:

```
   #btn {
        width: 250px;  height: 40px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        /*data-style: round;*/
        border: #000000;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 5px;
        font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
        font-size: 8pt;

        }
```

Solution founded in the answer below

Comment: I couldn't replicate your problem. it works for me. [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wbDsu/)

Comment: Try to set `font-size: 8pt !important;`

Comment: the same result. This issue can be reproduced on the Tizen emulator

Comment: 1.3.2 as per release notes [tizen 2.2.1](https://developer.tizen.org/ru/tizen-2.2.1-release-notes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed:

```
#btn span {
    text-align : right;
    font-size : 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try something like thisin the css

```
border-radius:8px ;
-moz-border-radius:8x;
-webtrik-border-radius:8px
```

Comment: I don't have a problem with borders

Comment: works fine when i tried it in fiddle , why don't you try the alternative like font-size:10px; or font-size:90%;

Comment: I tried all alternatives - px % pt and rem, it's not a js issue - I cant change it in the Tizen application